# Remove background from sprite sheet after splitting

Tags: libgdx, alpha-blending

I am using libgdx to implement a Parallax background. Now I need to show some animated object over the background. I downloaded a sprite sheet(with images of objects on white background), and split it using TextureRegion.split() method. But when I draw the objects to screen, white background is shown along with the object as in this image:[image: Removing white background]

I tried using batch.enableBlending() but it didn't work. Is there any way to resolve this issue? Or should I code only using individual sprites with transparent background? Here is a brief code snippet :

```
public class Animator extends Actor{
        int FRAME_COLS = 3, FRAME_ROWS = 3;

        Animation<TextureRegion> eagleAnimation;
        Texture eagleSheet;
        float stateTime;

        Animator(Texture sheet) {
            eagleSheet = sheet;
            TextureRegion[][] tmp = TextureRegion.split(eagleSheet, eagleSheet.getWidth()/FRAME_COLS,
                    eagleSheet.getHeight()/FRAME_ROWS);
            TextureRegion[] eagleFrames = new TextureRegion[FRAME_COLS*FRAME_ROWS];

            int index = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < FRAME_ROWS; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < FRAME_COLS; j++) {
                    eagleFrames[index++] = tmp[i][j];
                }
            }

            eagleAnimation = new Animation<TextureRegion>(0.09f, eagleFrames);
            stateTime = 0f;
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
            stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

            TextureRegion currentFrame = eagleAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
            batch.enableBlending(); // doesn't work
            batch.draw(currentFrame, 250, 250, 264, 264);

        }

    }
```

This is where I call above class from :

```
    public class GameScreen implements Screen {

        MyGdxGame game;

        Texture eagleSheet;
        OrthographicCamera camera;
        Array<Texture> layers;
        Stage stage;


        public GameScreen(MyGdxGame game) {
            this.game = game;
            stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
            camera = (OrthographicCamera) stage.getViewport().getCamera();

            layers = new Array<Texture>();

            for(int i = 1 ; i <= 6; i++) {
                layers.add(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("parallax/img" + i + ".png")));
            }
            ParallaxBackground parallaxBackground = new ParallaxBackground(layers);
            parallaxBackground.setSpeed(1);
            parallaxBackground.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
            stage.addActor(parallaxBackground);

            eagleSheet = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("eagle.png"));
            Animator animator = new Animator(eagleSheet);
            animator.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
            stage.addActor(animator);

        }

        @Override
        public void render (float delta) {
            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            stage.act();
            stage.draw();

        }

        @Override
        public void dispose () {
            stage.dispose();
        }


        @Override
        public void show() {}

        @Override
        public void hide(){}

        @Override
        public void resume(){}

        @Override
        public void resize(int x, int y){}

        @Override
        public void pause(){}

    }
```

Comment: In modern games, transparent spritesheet assets are usually stored on-disc in a format that supports transparency, like PNG or certain GPU-compatible formats, with a transparent background rather than an opaque colour. Do you have the ability to use such a format, and make the background transparent in an image editing tool prior to running your game? Or do you need to eliminate the background colour at runtime for some reason?

Comment: I don't necessarily need to eliminate at runtime right now. But if I ever need it in future, how would one go about it?

Comment: We have a [previous question covering some approaches](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/101228/39518)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Resolved this by editing image in TexturePacker, which makes background transparent.